# Are transparent JFrame backgrounds not possible in Windows 10?

Tags: java, swing, windows-10

I have a JPanel in an undecorated JFrame. I want to draw an image to the JPanel. When the image contains transparent pixels, I want these to be "see-through" so that you can see whatever is behind the window.

All my research has told me that I should make

```
myJFrame.setUndecorated(true);
myJFrame.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
myJPanel.setOpaque(false);
```

, but as soon as my JFrame's background color's alpha is anything else than 255, my JPanel is not being drawn to anymore.

Comment: Dunno about Windows 10, but what you describe (to the limited extent you describe it) works for me on Linux w/ Java 8.  Perhaps you can flesh your code out to a [mcve]?  You shouldn't need more than about 30 lines.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I strictly followed an example I found in another question's answer and suddenly it works. So I'm trying to find out what I did to make it not work.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I think I found something out. Apparently, you can't draw directly to the JPanel (using its `getGraphics()`), but you _can_ override the `paintComponent()` to draw an image to the JPanel, and you _can_ store an image in the class that extends JPanel and change that image and then call `myJPanel.repaint();`.

Comment: Well yes, if you want to perform custom painting on a `JComponent` then you should do so in the scope of its `paintComponent()` method.  Serving as a hook for such work is a large aspect of that method's *purpose*.  The `Graphics` that you receive that way is properly configured, whereas the one you get by invoking `getGraphics()` may not be.  You might consider refreshing yourself on these and other important details; here's one good resource for that: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, based on my limited testing, it seems to work fine on Windows 10

[image: Transparent Window]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setUndecorated(true);
                    frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setContentPane(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;

        public TestPane() throws IOException {
            img = ImageIO.read(...);
            setOpaque(false);
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int x = (getWidth() - img.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - img.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(img, x, y, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

And just to be sure, I did a test using a `JLabel`...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    try {
                        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setUndecorated(true);
                    frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.setContentPane(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() throws IOException {
            BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(...);
            setOpaque(false);
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED));
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img)));
        }

    }

}
```

This would suggest that the issue is somewhere in the code you're not showing us. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: May I ask where you get all those cool images? 1+ for those nice examples

Comment: I screwed around for a little bit and have discovered that you absolutely **have to** use `repaint()` to get something to show up on the JPanel. Any other method of trying to draw to it failed.

Comment: @JoFelix probably you did something wrong, I think there's no need to call `repaint()` in this case... Provide a [mcve] that demonstrates this issue

Comment: @JoFelix Based on my example you don't, unless you're updating the image after the frame has been made visible

Comment: @Frakcool They're from the web comic megatokyo, you can search deviant art for more

Comment: Thanks :) I'll take a look

Comment: @MadProgrammer of course I want to update the image later!

Comment: @JoFelix I wouldn't know what you want to do as you've not explained what it is you're trying to achieve and how you're trying to achieve it, so all I can do is make guesses, don't assume we know what you do. Depending on what it is you're trying to do, you may also need to call revalidate, which is all common practice for updating swing UIs, so your problem isn't with using transparent windows at all :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer to be honest I got sidetracked. I wasn't even focusing on transparent windows, but then I kinda wanted to find out what is possible. Well, I got my question answered (it's not Windows 10's fault), and that's what this place is about. Thanks very much for your help!